# ROW_NUMBER() Query Plan SORT Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan

The query below accesses the Votes table that contains over 30 million rows. The result set is then selected from using `WHERE n = 1`. In the query plan, the SORT operation in the ROW_NUMBER() windowed function is 95% of the query's cost and it is taking over 6 minutes to complete execution.

I already have an index on `same_voter, eid, country include vid, nid, sid, vote, time_stamp, new` to cover the where clause.

Is the most efficient way to correct this to add an index on `vid, nid, sid, new DESC, time_stamp DESC` or is there an alternative to using the ROW_NUMBER() function for this to achieve the same results in a more efficient manner?

```
SELECT v.vid, v.nid, v.sid, v.vote, v.time_stamp, v.new, v.eid,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY v.vid, v.nid, v.sid ORDER BY v.new DESC, v.time_stamp DESC) AS n
FROM dbo.Votes v
WHERE v.same_voter <> 1
    AND v.eid <= @EId
    AND v.eid > (@EId - 5)
    AND v.country = @Country
```

Comment: 95% for an operation is not that important,you have to look at the whole query.Is it really slow?The only thing I see is parameter sniffing issues since you have 2 parameters.The index is fine.https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: I stated in the question it's taking 6+ minutes to complete. Also, the index that you're referring to as being fine isn't related to the question/issue with the ROW_NUMBER() SORT being so expensive.

Comment: Index is bad since it starts from `same_voter` which is filtered `<> 1` (unless most of values are "1" and your index is filtered). I'd recommend to change index starting column to most selective in your case. Building full table of numbers (ROW_NUMBER) for taking _exactly the first/last ONE_ is not the best idea at all. You are giving no chances to sql server to use any index and just select min/max/top1. Your task to server is to enumerate all the rows and then... _ok i'll take first one_.

Comment: There's another pattern that can be used to accomplish the same tie breaker rule as row_number if the outer query is heavily filtered. Are you only wanting to find the latest vote for a small subsection of voters? If so, I can write up an answer.

Comment: `not exists (select <, >, !=)`, `outer apply ( top 1/min/max)` allow server to optimize and use `semi join`, also it would be a _correlated_ subquery which would also make it available to use another index if any. `ROW_NUMBER` is not free of charge. And every example where one demonstrates how he builds numbers for whole source and then filters out a single row - is the worst example ever. You won't feel it on `sandbox` tables of 1-10K rows. You'll feel it later. `ROW_NUMBER` means to server that you are not searching - you are building a new column on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I will try to restructure the query without using ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: Bruce I need the latest vote for every voter per `nid` and `sid`. For some voters, `new` is always 0 per `nid`/`sid`. For some voters, `new` can be 1. If that's the case, I want the latest vote where `new = 1`, if not - latest vote where `new = 0`. The `new` column is a bit field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible alternative to using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT
    V.vid,
    V.nid,
    V.sid,
    V.vote,
    V.time_stamp,
    V.new,
    V.eid
FROM
    dbo.Votes V
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Votes V2 ON
    V2.vid = V.vid AND
    V2.nid = V.nid AND
    V2.sid = V.sid AND
    V2.same_voter <> 1 AND
    V2.eid <= @EId AND
    V2.eid > (@EId - 5) AND
    V2.country = @Country AND
    (V2.new > V.new OR (V2.new = V.new AND V2.time_stamp > V.time_stamp))
WHERE
    V.same_voter <> 1 AND
    V.eid <= @EId AND
    V.eid > (@EId - 5) AND
    V.country = @Country AND
    V2.vid IS NULL
```

The query basically says to get all rows matching your criteria, then join to any other rows that match the same criteria, but which would be ranked higher for the partition based on the `new` and `time_stamp` columns. If none are found then this must be the row that you want (it's ranked highest) and if none are found that means that `V2.vid` will be `NULL`. I'm assuming that `vid` otherwise can never be `NULL`. If it's a `NULL`able column in your table then you'll need to adjust that last line of the query.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out. You're correct, `vid` is not nullable.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this. Thanks again.